# When should ginger beer's second fermentation start producing pressure?

Tags: secondary-fermentation, ginger-beer

I am trying my first batch of ginger beer, using what seems to be a pretty standard "fool proof" recipe.

For the bug:
2 cups filtered water; 2 tbsp chopped ginger; 2 tbs refined sugar
The ginger wasn't labeled organic, so I peeled it.  The fermentation started slowly, but by day 4, it looked fizzy enough to use.  The first day had a cheesecloth cover, but then my airlock top arrived, and I switched to that.  I bottled on day 4, but now on day 5, the bug is really active, and I wish I would've waited.

For the brew:
2 quarts water; 273 grams sugar; 54 grams ginger
Brought this to a boil, simmered 7 minutes, let *fully* cool to room temperature (paying attention to all of the warnings about the heat killing the yeast), strained, and added: 
1/2 cup of the bug (strained); 150 ml lemon juice
bottled it up into sterilized swing-tops, only filling to the "shoulders" of the bottles, for headroom.  Set them into the handily divided, cardboard shipping boxes from the swing-tops.

This morning, I went to burp the swing-tops, and the bottles seemed FLAT. I didn't hear any pressure, and didn't see any bubbles.  When should second fermentation start producing some bubbles and pressure?  Should I just be patient?  Would it help to add a splash of the now more active bug to the bottles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be patient, it is perfectly normal for there to be little to no pressure after the first day. Especially if you do not live somewhere hot to supercharge the yeast.

If you do not start seeing any activity by day 3 I'd add another half cup of your now very active ginger bug to get it started.

I live in a hot climate and I need 2 days for second fermentation, but in the winter it might take 2 days just to start noticing any activity at all in second fermentation.

Good luck with your ginger beer :)

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance.  Now, at 2.5 days in, after reading your post, I sadly went to burp my "flat" second fermentation, and heard an encouraging little, "pssss".  Thanks again, @Jeppe